# Replace null/blank columns with last known column (sed / awk / script)

Tags: linux, shell, sed, awk

Can someone help me figure out how to replace the empty columns with the last known value.  Here is a line that i would like the number "0.7588044" to replace the null values in this line:

```
0.7723808|0.767398|0.7645381|0.7605125|0.759718|0.7588044|0.7588044|0.7588044|0.7588044|0.7588044|0.7588044||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
```

In other words, I would like "0.7588044" to be between the empty/null "|" delimeters at the end of the line.

I can't figure out how to do this with something like sed.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here are the first 3 lines of my file:

```
66943|0.9939215|0.9873032|0.9791299|0.9708792|0.9623731|0.9535987|0.945847|0.9379317|0.9286675|0.9203091|0.9127985|0.9041528|0.8966769|0.8902251|0.8832675|0.8778407|0.8734665|0.8679647|0.8616999|0.8560756|0.8518617|0.8463235|0.8410841|0.8342401|0.8311638|0.8261909|0.8252836|0.8218218|0.8177906|0.815474|0.8122096|0.8115648|0.8108233|0.8108233|0.8108233|0.8108233|0.8108233|0.8108233||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
69550|0.9946427|0.9888051|0.9815896|0.9742986|0.966774|0.9590039|0.9521323|0.9451087|0.9368793|0.9294462|0.9227601|0.9150554|0.9083862|0.9026252|0.896407|0.8915528|0.8876377|0.8827099|0.8770942|0.8720485|0.8682655|0.8632902|0.8585799|0.8524216|0.8496516|0.8451712|0.8443534|0.8412323|0.8375956|0.8355048|0.8325575|0.8319751|0.8313053|0.8313053|0.8313053|0.8313053|0.8313053|0.8313053||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
380713|0.9942899|0.9880703|0.9803859|0.9726248|0.9646193|0.9563567|0.9490533|0.941592|0.9328543|0.9249665|0.917875|0.9097072|0.9026409|0.8965395|0.8899569|0.8848204|0.8806788|0.8754678|0.8695317|0.8642001|0.8602043|0.8549507|0.8499787|0.8434811|0.8405594|0.8358352|0.834973|0.8316831|0.8278509|0.8256481|0.8225436|0.8219303|0.8212249|0.8212249|0.8212249|0.8212249|0.8212249|0.8212249||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
```

The awk code works but just the first line:

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the following awk script:

```
awk -F'|' 'BEGIN{OFS="|"}{for(i=1;i<NF;i++){if($i==""){$i=l}else{l=$i}}print}'
```

It is better readable in this form:

```
BEGIN {
    OFS="|" # set output field separator to |
}
{
    for(i=1;i<NF;i++) { # iterate through columns
        if($i=="") { # if current column is empty
            $i=l # use the last value
        } else {
            l=$i # else store the value
        }
    }
    print # print the line
}
```

Comment: I was going to post this perl one-liner but you beat me to it with an awk one-liner: perl -ne '@fields = split /\|/; foreach (@fields) { print $sep; if($_ == "") { print $last } else { print $_; $last = $_; } $sep="|";}'

Comment: Why not giving this as an alternative? having alternatives is always great

Comment: Thank you both.  The awk script works great but i forgot to mention that there are more than one lines like this in my file.  It only seems to work on the first line of the file.  Is there modification that I need to make it work on an entire file?

Comment: @JohnRichardson Show more lines of your input file

Comment: Hek2mgl, I pasted the lines of the file in the original question because it didnt fit in comments section.  Thanks again!

Comment: @JohnRichardson .. My fault. `i` must be reset to `1` on each line ;) check my update

Comment: @JohnRichardson A `for` loop would be more appropriate here. have changed this

Comment: @hek2mgl, AWESOME!  you really saved me so much grief.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r ':a;s/^(.*\|([^|]+)\|)\|/\1\2|/;ta' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Some shorter version of solution hek2mgl

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<NF;i++) $i=($i=="")?l:l=$i}1' FS=\| OFS=\| file
```